# SharePoint thru MS GraphAPI, can get to site, drive is null

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I am fairly new to SharePoint. I am attempting to use the GraphAPI form Microsoft to upload documents into SharePoint. It looks like I need to get the site, then the drive, then the items, and add to that.

I can get the site of a sample SharePoint instance we stood up for testing with this call:
var site = await graphClient.Shares[UrlToSharingToken("https://[ourInstance]")].Site.Request().GetAsync();

But, when it comes back the drive and drives properties are null. I am not sure if we just set something up incorrectly in SharePoint or if my understanding is off.

Has anyone uploaded a document to SharePoint thru the GraphAPI?

Thanks,
Sammer

Edit:
So, following the example provided, I have this:

```
var site = graphClient.Shares[UrlToSharingToken(webUrl)].Site;
var targetDrive = site.Drive.Root;
var pathToFile = @"C:\TEMP\SharePoint.docx";
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var uploadedItem = await
    targetDrive
    .ItemWithPath("SharePoint.docx")
    .Content
    .Request()
    .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
}
```

I get the exception: Code: invalidRequest
Message: The encoded sharing link must be for a file or folder

If I provide a path:
    .ItemWithPath(@"C:\TEMP\SharePoint.docx")
I get the exception: Code: BadRequest
Message: Only one path can be specified in the URL.

Not sure what to try next.

Sammer

Answer (score 0):

The following example demonstrates how to upload a file into SharePoint Online document library:

```
var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient();

var webUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/";
var site = graphClient.Shares[UrlToSharingToken(webUrl)].Site;
var targetDrive = site.Drive.Root;

var pathToFile = @"c:\Docs\Guide.docx";
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
     var uploadedItem = await
                targetDrive
               .ItemWithPath("Guide.docx")
               .Content
               .Request()
               .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);

}
```

where

```
static string UrlToSharingToken(string inputUrl)
{
        var base64Value = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputUrl));
        return "u!" + base64Value.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/', '_').Replace('+', '-');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have added some additional details outlining my attempt to use this method to my question above.